# Simple regex not working in c#

Tags: c#, regex

> /news/article-title.html

is not being caught by the regex:

> ^/news/[^(archives)].+.html

?

I'm trying to have articles that do NOT have "archives" in the filename, but start with "/news/"

Thanks!

Comment: `[]` defines _one_ character from a character class. `[^(archives)]` translates to "one character that is not one of these: `archives()`".

Comment: so how do I say "not the entire string 'archives'" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) only work for a single character.  Also, don't forget to escape the dot.

If "archives" cannot be at the beginning:

```
^/news/(?!archives).+\.html
```

If "archives" cannot anywhere:

```
^/news/((?!archives).)+\.html
```

More tips:

- Disallow `archives` as a whole word: `(?!archives\b).+` or `(?!archives-).+`
- make sure `\.html` is at the end (it may appear more than once): `\.html(?=$|[?&])`

Comment: Why be so specific about unspecified forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the not of a character block to not an entire string.

```
[^(archives)]
```

This is interpreted as a character that is not one of the following: (, a, r, c, h, i, v, e, s or ).